# How do I automatically insert the auth user id when creating a new model with a foreign key in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have a 'projects' table in my Laravel project. The migration looks something like this:

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('key')->nullable();
    $table->integer('bpm')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('is_collaborative')->default(false);
    $table->foreignId('owner_id')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want the `owner_id` field to reference a user's id in order to know who the owner of the project is (since projects will be collaborative and multiple users will have access to them).

After creating the following method on my Project model:

```
public function owner(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner_id');
    }
```

And the following method on my User model:

```
public function projectsOwned(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class, 'owner_id');
    }
```

I implemented the `store` function on my ProjectController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the data input by the user.
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'max:255'],
        ]);

        // Create a new project.
        auth()->user()->projects()->create($validatedData);

        return to_route('projects.index')->with('status', __('Project created successfully!'));
    }
```

The thing is, this function will throw the following exception:
`General error: 1364 Field 'owner_id' doesn't have a default value` when executed.

What can I do to make Laravel automatically insert the authenticated user's id into the `owner_id` field without having to add `owner_id` to the `$fillable` array of the Project model?

PS: I also have a many-to-many relationship between users and projects to keep track of who has access to which projects. That's why I use the `auth()->user()->projects()` method when trying to store a new project in the database.

Comment: You should put `owner_id` key into `$fillable` array of Project model.

Comment: @Tpojka so that wouldn't create any security issues? I'm new to Laravel but I though you were supposed to only fill the $fillable array with the columns that might receive data input directly by users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So your migrations and models should look like this (though I think they already do):

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
});
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('owner_id')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->string('title');
});
Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
});

class User extends Model {
    public function projects(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }
    public function ownedProjects(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class, 'owner_id');
    }
}

class Projects extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'owner_id'];

    public function users(): BelongsToMany {
        return this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
    public function owner(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

With that in place you can create new **owned** models with either of these statements:

```php
$project = auth()->user()
    ->ownedProjects()
    ->save(new Project(['title' => 'New project']));

$project = auth()->user()
    ->ownedProjects()
    ->create(['title' => 'New project']);
```

Or new associated models like this:

```php
$project = auth()->user()
    ->projects()
    ->save(new Project(['title' => 'New project', 'owner_id' => $owner_user_id]));

$project = auth()->user()
    ->projects()
    ->create(['title' => 'New project', 'owner_id' => $owner_user_id]);
```

You need to either use the `ownedProjects` relationship to create the new models or manually insert the owner, because the `projects()` relationship doesn't have any awareness of the `owner_id` column.

See live demo [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/4a7cc59c-9c7a-4ba7-8241-65bcc6613bc3).

Comment: Thanks! So there wouldn't be any security problems if I put `owner_id` in the `$fillable` array of the Project model? I'm new to Laravel but I though you were supposed to only fill the `$fillable` array with the columns that might receive data input directly by users.

Comment: No, it indicates which columns you will be passing in a new model creation call. As opposed to individually like `$p = new Project(); $p->owner_id=3; $p->save()`. It's up to you to ensure that if a user shouldn't be submitting `owner_id` then it doesn't make it into your creation call.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this should do the job. `auth()->user()->projects()->create($validatedData);`. In your case, it fails.

You can try one more alternative way to set this value.

In the model

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($project) {
        if (empty($project->owner_id)) {
            $project->owner_id = auth()->id();
        }
    });
}
```

> Supported methods: `creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`, and `deleted`

---

> Note: `booted` introduced in Laravel 8, defines code that should be executed after the model has booted

More to read

- [Using the booted Method in Laravel Eloquent Models for CRUD Event Listening and Cache Resetting - from  `dev.to`](https://dev.to/junaidjaved248/using-the-booted-method-in-laravel-eloquent-models-for-crud-event-listening-and-cache-resetting-4519)
- [`boot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#main-content)
- [`booted()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#applying-global-scopes)

Answer (score -1):

Laravel has conventions that you would need to follow to get this to work.  Even though you are using owner_id I don't see an owners table, it is looking for user_id on the users table.  You're also calling in your store function:

```
auth()->user()->projects()->create($validatedData);
```

This is also looking for the auth user's id and auth is only associated with the authenticated user, not any other model.

If you really need and owner_id field, you can create an owners table and reference your user on that before you can reference it on the projects table from the owners. Then on your store functions you can find the owner by id and then store but also since this isn't authenticated from the user model you'll have to either make sure owner_id is in your fillable properties on your models or you can use guarded instead(I never recommend guarded when you're learning).

Keep in mind, migrations need to be in order so have your main migrations listed before your relations tables. Users, then owners, then projects.

Comment: Re "it is looking for user_id on the users table": it's not, because the relationship definition explicitly includes both the `User` class and the `owner_id` column name, meaning it's looking for a link between `projects.owner_id` and `users.id` which is correct.

Comment: Based on the code the op posted the fn they put to store the project, that function the way it's written is in fact looking for the user id.  Op has not shown a projects relationship specifying the projects directly but a projectsOwned and owners relation and in the store function it's calling for projects. The store function isn't calling the "relationship definition" in this case and explicitly they have to add the owner_id in this call which is not automatic as the question asked. It's not going to find the value of the owner id on it's own as the way it's written will look for the user id.

Comment: They only mention the `projects` relationship right at the end and not in the code; I missed it at first as well.

Comment: It's all good, we try to help as best we can and if we can't see how the code is written then it makes it tougher when we're not working on the same projects. Happy coding!